# How to NOT match a word in mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

Please help, I'm going crazy!

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)?/?search/?$ search.php?id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

This is my current code. Sometimes people will visit mysite.com/search, other times they will visit mysite.com/boris/search and I detect a user with an empty($_GET['id']) check.

However I am creating another search, mysite.com/products/search which leads to products_search.php

I need my original RewriteRule to match any user EXCEPT the word 'products'.

I have tried so many combinations.

```
RewriteRule ^(!products&[a-z0-9_-]+)?/?search/?$ search.php?id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

I'm not very good with regex/mod_rewrite but I something like the above should work? I just need an AND operator as clearly & doesn't work, but I can't find one!

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have two options: Either use a `RewriteCond` to restrict the already matched string:

```
RewriteCond $1 !=products
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)?/?search/?$ search.php?id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

Or since Apache 2, you can also use a negated look-ahead assertion:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!products/)([a-z0-9_-]+)?/?search/?$ search.php?id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

Besides that, you can also use the [*QSA* flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) instead of appending *QUERY_STRING* manually. And note that your current pattern will also allow something like `/foobarsearch/`, so it doesn’t have the separating `/`.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! Because I used the [L] flag, I ended up just putting the products line first.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly "Not matching a word" - but you can add a Condition on the rewrite to say "If the URL doesn't match this pattern"

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/products
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)?/?search/?$ search.php?id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

Which is generally the most common way to do things like this - as conditions can also be chained together.

You can find more information about RewriteCond here :-
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Answer (score 1):

If mod_rewrite supports lookaheads, you can use

```
RewriteRule ^(?!products)([a-z0-9_-]+)?/?search....
```

According [to this question on serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/120971/regex-negative-look-ahead-is-not-working-for-mod-rewrite-between-different-apache) newer versions do.

The part `(?!products)` tells the regex engine to look ahead and fail if it finds "products".