# Regex to match uri path except a certain page

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, nginx

I am trying to write a regular expression in nginx that will match all paths under `/wp-admin` except for `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`. Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to NOT match a word in mod\_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987160/how-to-not-match-a-word-in-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a negative lookahead, you can exclude that particular site:

```
^/wp-admin(?!/admin-ajax\.php)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
location /wp-admin/ {
    # here is config for /wp-admin/* except /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

    location = /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php {
        # here is config for /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
    }
}
```

or

```
location /wp-admin/ {
    # here is config for /wp-admin/* except /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
}

location /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php {
    # here is config for /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
}
```